# Ways to find messages from blocked contact info

Tags: macbook-pro, iphone, finder, email, messages

Is there a way, or ways, to retrieve iMessages or text messages sent to me by a number or email address I have blocked on my iPhone 6?

Comment: idk for certain, but everything i've read about iPhone blocking would tell me the messages were never saved at all.

Comment: Well I find it interesting that, even tho one is never notified or made aware that a blocked contact has called & left a voicemail, the person that blocked the contact info (with my iPhone 6) is able to tell that the contact has indeed called & left a voicemail, but only if/when they go to their VM screen and look below "Deleted Messages" where there is a "Blocked Messages" selection.  I figured it was worth a shot in asking!!

Comment: not sure why the vm is not also blocked, but the block itself for voice calls just 'doesn't answer' sending it off to the provider's vm, if enabled - same as pressing any hardware button whilst it's ringing.

Comment: To read messages in the block box, on the Messages screen, tap ▼ > Block

Comment: Actually that isn't entirely true. When a blocked contact 'calls' it rings only once, then prompts that the number is unavailable w/the option to leave a vm. While I realize this is basically what u just stated, the difference is that, if desired, the blocked contact can bypass being blocked a number of different ways, specifically to see if they HAVE been blocked b/c if they do so, unless the voicemail is set to do it with all or some of it's calls, they will get a different outcome such as several rings before going to vm or something else.

Comment: thanks Buscar, but the only "Messages" screen I find is within "Settings" and that is only showing a list of any contact info that IS blocked.  Not Blocked Messages or any option to do so. When opening my Messages with the icon there is no "Blocked Messages" selection as is with the voicemail. Any other ideas anyone???

Answer (score 1):

Text messages that are blocked are not saved. So you cannot go in to see old text messages.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a MacBook (I have MacBook Air), you can easily tell if someone has blocked you. With the new iMessage service *every* message appears as "delivered" (blocked or unblocked), however if your MacBook Air is synced with your iPhone, you will *not* see a delivered notification on the very same message your iPhone is showing as "delivered".

Answer (score 0):

Tap the Phone Icon.Then tap the Voicemail Icon. Scroll to the very bottom, and if anyone left a voice mail while the number was blocked, it will be listed under Blocked, and you can play them back.

Comment: IP is asking about text messages and iMessages, not voicemails. But handy tip.

Answer (score -1):

If you have been blocked the phone will ring once then go straight to voicemail  or it will go straight to voicemail without ringing. A text message will show as delivered but the person will never see it. If it has a single green tick next to it it means you have been blocked.

Comment: What are you referring to by the 'single green tick'? Are you confusing iMessage and another messaging service?